# spring boot tomcat deploy without extends SpringBootServletInitializer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to deploy my spring boot via Tomcat9 however if I don't extend `SpringBootServletInitializer` my app is not starting. Why should I do this? Are there any other alternatives? I remember a few years ago I was able to deploy without extending it.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
  }
}


 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.12</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  ...........
  <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
  </properties>
  ............
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: It is simply required to package your app as a war when using spring boot.